# Redmine: Unable to get gmail email notification to work

Tags: email, gmail, redmine

I've recently installed Redmine in an Amazon EC2 instance and it seems to be working fine, however, I can't figure out how to set email notifications.

Redmine documentation is pretty outdated and I've already tried a lot of alternatives. Take into account that I'm not a RoR programmer.

This is my configuration.yml file:

```
...
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      tls: true
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.gmail.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "dnd1.com" # 'your.domain.com' for GoogleApps
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "daniel@mycompany.com"
      password: "mypassword"
...
```

I keep getting back this error:

```
(SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the

```
tls: true
```

part of your configuration, restart your Redmine server if you are running it standalone and check if it works.

Comment: For gmail, specifically, one has to configure security for less secure apps also! This last step drove me crazy for a couple of hours...